# Calling 'nuxt-link' behavior after async request

Tags: nuxt.js

I am new to nuxt.js and building my first application using this framework.

I want to use transitions between my pages. I know I can achieve this by using the `<nuxt-link>` tag. However, I want this behavior to occur after sending a successful async ajax (in this case login) request.

So in my case, I want to link to another page after a successful login, while also showing the transition between the pages.

When I use the default javascript approach, it doesn't show the transition: 
`window.location.href = '...'`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Official Vue Router documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html)

As explained you should use:

```
router.push('another')
```

So, in nuxt

```
this.$router.push('another')
```

Remember that you have to define a transition between pages using for example opacity. (As official documentation explain)

```
.page-enter-active,
.page-leave-active {
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-duration: .5s;
}
.page-enter,
.page-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html) section of the vue-router docs for how to do programmatic navigation.  In Nuxt, the router is automatically attached to the component, and is accessible using `this.$router`.

Something like this will work

```
// Other Vue properties omitted
methods: {
    async login() {
        await loginUser()

        this.$router.push('/..')
    }
}
```